# Assign ID to all vertexes of the same instance (geometry nodes)

Tags: geometry-nodes

Essentially I want to distribute instances on points using geometry nodes, then realize instances and transform each one according to their index. Example (all instances with index 1 are tranformed by face extrude node, all instances with index 2 get "shrink wraped" using raycast nodes...)

Idealy I would want to make a grid from objects from 2 selections and "shrink wrap" each object from selection 1 with a predetermined object from selection 2.

But I am also interested, if the functionality of indexing the instances after "realize instance" node is supported. I feel like I could use it a lot in other projects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> all instances with index 1 are tranformed

Well, obviously, once you use *Realize Instances*, they're not gonna be *instances* anymore, so they won't have instance indices, but you could perhaps employ the *Island Index* from the *Mesh Island* node:

[image]

As they're not instances, you are actually somewhat freer with your transformations, since you can manipulate one's geometry without affecting the others, if you like. In the screenshot, you can see that every third island (*Modulo 3*) is separated into a different group and colored white, but I am also extruding half of all units regardless of their coloring.

If you wanted to turn some of them back to instances, you could use the *Separate Geometry* node and feed the selection into a *Geometry to Instance*, then perhaps distributing them on points of mesh island positions etc...

Comment: Looks promising will see if i can implement it this way.